# Verification of "div." and just "."

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

In my html file, I wrote the code like this,

```
<body class="sign-in-body">
<div class="container sign-in-container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col"> </div>
      <div class="col-8">
          <div class="card">
              <div class="card-block">
                This is some text within a card block.
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col"> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to add a `margin-top: 15%` to my container class. To do that I wrote,

```
div.container.sign-in-container {
    margin-top: 15%;
}
```

But the problem is if I add just,

```
.container.sign-in-container
```

it works.
Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selector `.container.sign-in-container` will select any element that has both `container` and `sign-in-container` classes.

But `div.container.sign-in-container` will select only the `div` elements with both of the `css` classes.

Since you have only a `div` with both classes, both of the selectors work.

You should probably read about `css` selectors. [This](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) is a good reference to start.

Answer (score 0):

In css you add only one class for css not necessary to add `div.container.sign-in-container`. This is also work in one class `.sign-in-container`. If you want to override css then you can use parent of div.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a class level CSS selector. It will work. You can have multiple kinds of [selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) and [combinators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Combinators_and_multiple_selectors) in CSS to target the element on your page.

With your example

---

```
div.container.sign-in-container
div.sign-in-container
div.container
.container.sign-in-container
.container
.sign-in-container
```

---

all are going to target the same div, that is why it works.